# Unwanted but invisible unicode character

Tags: bibliographies, cross-referencing

My Tex document has acquired an invisible unwanted character. I want to remove it but cannot see it.

It has come in a new citation from my Bibtex file but it is not visible in Bibtex either.

Here is the error message I get when I try to compile the Tex document:

```
! LaTeX Error: Unicode character ï¿Œ (U+FFFC)
               not set up for use with LaTeX.

See the LaTeX manual or LaTeX Companion for explanation.
Type  H <return>  for immediate help.
 ...                                              
                                                  
l.35 Bojke, Laura~ï¿Œ
                     , S. M. ï. C. K. ï. e.~a. (2021) Developing a reference
? 
Process aborted
```

What can I do?

Comment: just open the `.bib` file in  text editor find `Laura,` back delete from the `,` and retype `Laura,` without the control character

Comment: Taken from a comment by Ulrike: `\DeclareUnicodeCharacter{FFFC}{HEREHEREHERE}` might work. You might need to look at the encodings of the files you use.

Comment: U+FFFC is OBJECT REPLACEMENT CHARACTER  which implies there was some malformed unicode encode text at some earlier stage and some application has deleted the malformed btes and replaced it with this marker, so you may want to go back to an authorattive source and check what _should_ be after `Laura` rather than simply deleting the marker

Comment: If it is this https://pubmed.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/34105510/  I'd guess U+FCCC was originally the superscript footnote marker, `ï.` should be some kind of space and `e.~a.` should be `etc.`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can easily make the error go away: just open the `.bib` file in text editor find `Laura,` back delete from the `,` and retype `Laura,` without the control character

**However**
U+FFFC is OBJECT REPLACEMENT CHARACTER which implies there was some malformed unicode encoded text at some earlier stage and some application has deleted the malformed bytes and replaced it with this marker. So you may want to go back to an authoritative source and check what should be after Laura rather than simply deleting the marker

If it is [this document at pubmed](https://pubmed.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/34105510)

[image]

I'd guess `U+FCCC` was originally the superscript footnote marker, `ï.` should be some kind of space and `e.~a.` should be `et. al.` As such it seems the bib entry has been through some incorrect text encoding and is probably garbled for any non ascii text. Rather than simply deleting the control characters you may want to write the full bib entry from scratch in a correct encoding.